# Error Passing Variable to Include in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, html, apache

Index.php

```
if (!$result)  
{  
    $error = 'No value found.';
    include 'error.html';  
    exit();  
}  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
    $myvalues[] = $row['ValueID'];   
}  
include 'output.html';
exit();
```

Output.php

```
<?php foreach ($myvalues as $allmyvalues): ?>  
    <?php echo $allmyvalues; ?>  
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Error is "Undefined variable: myvalues in ...output.php" The rest of the page displays properly.

Using Apache 2.2.15/PHP 5.3

Any idea what is wrong? Basically everything seems to be functioning, however $myvalues are not getting passed. Running this on a Windows 2k box, so I don't think upgrading Apache/PHP is an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just declare a variable `$myvalues = array();` on very top of the code you provided. You're are referencing an uninitialized variable

Comment: Fatal Error or Notices/Warnings ?

Comment: output.html vs output.php - typo or worse?

Comment: @Mahan that is not necessary.  PHP will instantiate it as an array for you implicitly.  http://3v4l.org/lLXeX

Comment: Notice on the undefined variable; also a warning that an invalid argument is supplied for foreach() (but I assume that the variable passing issue will fix that).

Output.html vs. output.php is a typo here...both are output.php in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're assuming there are no results found if `$result` is `false`; however, that return value is only returned if there was a query error. An empty result set is still considered a successful query result. I would recommend moving the logic around a bit:

```
$myvalues = array();
if ($result) {
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
        $myvalues[] = $row['ValueID'];
    }
}
if (empty($myvalues)) {
    $error = 'No value found.';
    include 'error.html';  
    exit();  
}  
include 'output.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read from top to bottom of your code, you'll realise that if no rows are returned from your query, your `$myvalues` array never gets anything added to it.

PHP may let you add values to an undefined array, but that in itself is bad practice. You should declare your array as empty before you try and use it (whether that be during your loop or when you're outputting the results).

You should also check that variables exist before you use them, especially when they are only created conditionally.

```
$myvalues = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    $myvalues[] = $row['ValueID'];

// here, you can use foreach on the array, because you've given it an empty default value
```

An example of conditional definition would be:

```
if($foo)
    $bar = 'baz';

echo $bar; // could easily be undefined

// You should instead check its existence first

if(isset($bar)) echo $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write this in `Output.php` :

```
if(isset($myvalues)) //Check of Existence first, Then Loop it if exists.
{
    foreach ($myvalues as $allmyvalues){
     echo $allmyvalues; 
     }
}
```

But it always a best practice to declare the variable `$myvalues = array();` before you use them.

Answer (score 0):

One reason can be that you are including `output.html` instead of `output.php` and other can be that you are not declaring `$myvalues` as array. Try the code below

```
$myvalues=array();
    if (!$result)  
    {  
        $error = 'No value found.';
        include 'error.html';  
        exit();  
    }  
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
        $myvalues[] = $row['ValueID'];   
    }  
    include 'output.php';
    exit();
```

Hope this helps you